# Laravel 5.4 Datatables plugin

Tags: laravel-5.4, yajra-datatable

I am trying to use [yajara-laravel-database](https://github.com/yajra/laravel-datatables)

This is my controller

```
public function index(Request $request){
    $posts = Datatables::eloquent(Posts::query())->make(true);
    return View::make('dashboard.approval', compact('posts'));
}
```

This is my View

```
    <table class="ui celled table">
  <thead>
    <tr><th>id</th>
    <th>Title</th>
    <th>Description</th>
  </tr></thead>
  <tbody>
  @foreach($posts as $post)
    <tr>
        <td>lsdjflajsdlk</td>
        <td>Hello</td>
        <td>Hello</td>
    </tr>
    @endforeach
  </tbody>

</table>
@endsection
```

This is my script tag

```
<script>
   $(document).ready(function(){
          $('.table').DataTable({

            });
        });
      </script>
```

I am getting the datatable structure. But currently i am getting only 3 rows but i have 7 rows of data and i verified by putting {{$posts}} in html view.

**HTML View of {{$posts}}**

```
HTTP/1.0 200 OK Cache-Control: no-cache, private Content-Type: application/json {"draw":0,"recordsTotal":7,"recordsFiltered":7,"data":[{"id":"1",".............],"queries":[{"query":"select count(*) as aggregate from (select '1' as `row_count` from `posts`) count_row_table","bindings":[],"time":70.87},{"query":"select * from `posts`","bindings":[],"time":2.22}],"input":[]}
```

I tried putting {{$post->id}} and got this error

```
Undefined property: Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ResponseHeaderBag::$id
```

Tried code{{$post}}

```
htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given
```

What is the procedure to populate the data. The wiki urls are not working

Answer (score 1):

Populating data using yajra-datatables does not work like this. `When you use Yajra-Datatables it returns the data in Json format and we have to populate it using jquery datatables`.

**Please follow these steps:**

> Make new method for returning the data using yajra-datables

```
//this will return the data in json form
public function getPosts() 
{
    return Datatables::eloquent(Posts::query())->make(true);

}
```

> Now make a route for that

```
//You can check the response by hitting this route
Route::get('getPosts', 'PostController@getPosts' )->name('get.posts');
```

> Your view should not have following lines,

```
 <tbody>
  @foreach($posts as $post)
    <tr>
        <td>lsdjflajsdlk</td>
        <td>Hello</td>
        <td>Hello</td>
    </tr>
    @endforeach
 </tbody>
```

> This is how we populate data

```
//This is how we populate the data
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.table').DataTable({
        processing: true,
        serverSide: true,
        ajax: '{!! route('get.posts') !!}',

        //You will have to give the column names of the table.
        columns: [
            { data: 'name', name: 'name' },
            { data: 'phone', name: 'phone' },
            { data: 'message', name: 'message' },

        ]
    });
});
</script>
```

Here is [Docs](https://datatables.yajrabox.com/starter)